# Unexpected end of file in while loop in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, unexpectendoffile

I am trying to write a bash script that will do the following:

1. Take a directory or file as input (will always begin with /mnt/user/)
2. Search other mount points for same file or directory (will always begin with /mnt/diskx)
3. Return value

So, for example, the input will be "/mnt/user/my_files/file.txt". It will search if ""/mnt/disk1/my_files/file.txt" exists and will incrementally look for each disk (disk2, disk3, etc) until it finds it or disk20.

This is what I have so far:

```
#/user/bin/bash
var=$1
i=0
while [ -e $check_var = echo $var | sed 's:/mnt/user:/mnt/disk$i+1:']
do
final=$check_var
done
```

It's incomplete yes, but I am not that proficient in bash so I'm doing a little at a time. I'm sure my command won't work properly yet either but right now I am getting an "unexpected end of file" and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Have you heard of the `find` command?

Comment: Your while condition syntax is incorrect, and it's probably the cause to the unexpected EOF error.

Comment: What are you attempting with :`-e $check_var = echo $var`?  You are missing a space before the final `]`, and the `$i` inside the `sed` replacement will not be substituted because you are using single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I thought about using "find" but I couldn't really think if a simpler way of doing it with that without introducing the possibility of false positives and introducing complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues here:

- If this is the actual code you're getting "unexpected end of file" on, you should save the file in Unix format, not DOS format.
- The shebang should be `#!/usr/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/bash` depending on your system
- You have to assign `check_var` before running `[ .. ]` on it.
- You have to use `$(..)` to expand a command
- Variables like `$i` are not expanded in single quotes
- `sed` can't add numbers
- `i` is never incremented
- the loop logic is inverted, it should loop until it matches and not while it matches.
- You'd want to assign `final` after -- not in -- the loop.

Consider doing it in even smaller pieces, it's easier to debug e.g. the single statement `sed 's:/mnt/user:/mnt/disk$i+1:'` than your entire while loop.

Here's a more canonical way of doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="${1#/mnt/user/}"
for file in /mnt/disk{1..20}/"$var"
do
  [[ -e "$file" ]] && final="$file" && break
done

if [[ $final ]]
then
  echo "It exists at $final"
else
  echo "It doesn't exist anywhere"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps out a lot. I changed the shebang because I was getting an error but after the comments I looked back on it and it was because of CR issues that I thought I fixed. Same with my initial "unexpected EOF" error. I never incremented i because I hadn't gotten that far.